# Postgres select duplicates of emails in different char cases

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have users table which have duplicates emails in different char cases. For example, in users table I have 2 records, one is EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.COM and second is example@example.com

How can I find all these duplicates using Postgres?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? Or the logic of what you might consider a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `upper` function with `group by` and `having`:

```
select upper(string)
from userstable
group by upper(string)
having count(1) >1
```

Comment: Thanks! I was close to that, but I'm using wrong query (with id column):

`select id, upper(email)
from users
group by id, upper(email)
having count(email) > 1;`